# Control white space bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I created a bibliography using the `biblatex` package. It creates a bibliography with numbers (e.g., [1] Author, etc). Is it possible to control the space between the number (e.g., "[1]") and the text (e.g. "Author, etc.")?

For example, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
    @book{author2018,
        author = {Author, A.},
        publisher = {The big publish company},
        title = {A book},
        year = {2018}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
    I found a book \cite{author2018}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The generated file is shown below (together with my question in red).

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The space is controlled by the length `\biblabelsep`, its default value is `2\labelsep`. You can change it to whatever value you like

```
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{\labelsep}
```

or

```
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks!